# java timer task schedule

Tags: java, timer, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

From reading on Stack Overflow I've seen that many of you don't recommend using Timer Task. Hmmm... but I already implemented this:

I have this code:

```
detectionHandlerTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 60 * 1000, 60 * 1000);
```

The thing is that work of myTimerTask lasts some time.

I would like this behavior:

1. wait 60 sec.
2. do task for some time (e.g. 40 - 100 sec).
3. task finished.
4. wait 60 seconds.
5. do task for some time (e.g. 40 - 100 sec).

But the code above behaves like this

1. wait 60 sec.
2. do task for some time (e.g. 40 - 100 sec).
3. task finished
4. do task for some time (e.g. 40 - 100 sec).

Because the time duration of task is bigger than 60, timer starts task immediately after task is finished. But I would like it to wait again.

Comment: you can take a look at spring scheduling capabilities or directly in the quartz scheduler project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works. The key is to have the task itself (after it completes) schedule the next occurrence of the task.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TaskManager {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskManager manager = new TaskManager();
        manager.startTask();
    }

    public void startTask() {
        timer.schedule(new PeriodicTask(), 0);
    }

    private class PeriodicTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Running");

            /* replace with the actual task */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* end task processing */

            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " Scheduling 10 seconds from now");
            timer.schedule(new PeriodicTask(), 10 * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
$ javac TaskManager.java && java TaskManager
1288282514688 Running
1288282529711 Scheduling 10 seconds from now
1288282539712 Running
1288282554713 Scheduling 10 seconds from now
1288282564714 Running
```

Here's what it looks like if you extract the second components of the timestamps (for clarity):

```
$ javac TaskManager.java && java TaskManager
14                                    Running
29 (+15 seconds execution)            Scheduling 10 seconds from now
39 (+10 seconds delay until next run) Running
54 (+15 seconds execution)            Scheduling 10 seconds from now
64 (+10 seconds delay until next run) Running
```

Just replace the `10`s with `60`s.

Comment: Yes; I found out when you want to reschedule the timer; a new instance of timerTask is needed.