# Why is run() getting called just once?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

Consider this class, `AnimationThread`:

```
class AnimationThread implements Runnable {
    public void pause() {
        doAnimation = false;
    }

    public void doStart(){
        doAnimation = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (doAnimation) {
            //my code
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Now I am starting this thread in `onCreate` of an activity (just showing rough code):

```
AnimationThread animRunnable = new AnimationThread();
animationThread = new Thread(animRunnable);
animationThread.start();
```

But `run()` is getting called just once (I traced a log to confirm that). I just want to know that when I started the thread why `run()` is not getting called repeatedly with 500 sleep. It is just called once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is how it is supposed to be.

A Thread runs by executing its run method (just once). After that it is considered done/dead/finished/completed.

If you want to loop, you have to do it yourself (inside of the run method), or use some ExecutorService to call the Runnable repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. I got the logic. I am making sure inside run my logic code is running repeatedly. Actually in my situation i want run() to execute infinetly for my purpose so i have enclosed my logic within while(true) inside run and animation occurs based on state of doAnimation state variable. Thanks.

Comment: That is a common pattern. However, you probably want the thread to terminate eventually in order to shutdown the program. Or you could use a daemon thread for that.

Answer (score 8):

Of course the `run()` method will be executed once. If you want to repeat the statements inside the `run` method then you have to use loop. Take a look at [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) - will runs  a task at a specified time  or repeatedly.

EDIT:

1. [Android - Controlling a task with Timer and TimerTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161750/android-controlling-a-task-with-timer-and-timertask)
2. [Timer task schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044729/java-timer-task-schedule)